# How would you make a function with a while and for loop to return the last item in a list?

Tags: java

Say I had a method finalNum() where I want to use this method to pick out the final number in a list i.e. {1,2,10,12} and returns 12

What is the simplest way to do so using a for loop vs a while loop? Can someone show both? I'm new to code and trying to find a simple example.

Comment: Looping is not the way to go here. Think of accessing the last element using its index.

Answer (score 1):

Since Lists are based on arrays which are zero-indexed, the last element is the element at index `list.size() - 1`. Using [`List#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) will suffice; there is no need for looping at all.

```
final List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,10,12);
final Integer last = list.get(list.size() - 1);//12
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to solve this question for educating purposes, you can take a look at these examples.

Here we loop from the beginning to the end and saving each element of the list to a variable. After we have finished looping we return the value which is by definition the last element of the list

```
static int finalNum(List<Integer> listOfNumbers) {
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < listOfNumbers.length(); ++i) {
    result = listOfNumbers.get(i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

You can do it the other way around, too:

```
static int finalNum(List<Integer> listOfNumbers) {
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = listOfNumbers.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    return listOfNumbers.get(i);
  }
  throw new IllegalStateException("list contains no elements");
}
```

That loop goes from the end to the beginning. So the loop does not actually loop. This is mostly not what the developer wants or has intended.

The first example as a while loop

```
static int finalNum(List<Integer> listOfNumbers) {
  int result = 0;
  Iterator<Integer> iterator = listOfNumbers.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext())
    result = iterator.next();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here we also loop from the beginning to the end storing everything in a variable which we return as result at the very end.

But after all, none of this is recommend as you can easily access the last element of a list via `list.get(list.size() - 1)`. *The above code is by no means code for production*.